pandas join 2 dataframes using calculated ranking
I have 2 dataframes. Dataframe1 has millions of rows containing data and Dataframe2 has thousands of rows containing rules. I want to join a row in df1 with a row in df2 by calculating rank using custom logic by comparing id1,id2 and id3 columns, in some cases i have to just compare id1 in df1 with id1 in df2 and so on and in some cases i have to perform a calculation to calculate the rank. I don't want to use cartesian join. I want to calculate rank and join the row in dataframe1 with dataframe2 that have highest rank.

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "id1": [1001, 1005, 1009, 1010],
    "id2": [9001, 9001, 2001, 9001],
    "id3": [3001, 3001, 3001, 5001],
    "value1": ["blue", "yellow", "black", "blue"],
    "value2": ["square", "circle", "rectangle", "star"],
    "value3": [True, False, True, False],
}
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "id1": [1001, 1001, None, None, 1001, 1001],
    "id2": [9001, None, 9001, 9001, 9001, None],
    "id3": [3001, None, None, 3001, None, 3001],
    "valuex": [1000, 200, 200, 1000, 1001, 1001],
    "valuey": [2.5, 1.0, 5.4, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5],
    "valuez": [5, 3, 0, 6, 7, 7],
}
)

To explain the ranking logic, I am comparing ID1, ID2 and ID3 values in df1 with ID1, ID2 and ID3 values in df2. If all these columns match, it yields the rank of 1. If only ID1 values match or only 2 ID columns match, the rank will be different. For a row in DF1, if there are many rank values, i will consider the lowest and join the row in DF1 with DF2 that produced lowest rank value.
I have tried posting this question before but i have deleted all my old posts.

Images of data are not acceptable, please provide a [mre] as code/text.

Also, the logic is not clear, please explain how the rows are matching

You can perform a merge on all combinations of keys, then keep the highest rank (I used the number of matching keys as rank here, so higher is better 3>2>1).
How you chose the "best" row within a single rank remains to be defined, here I took the first.
from itertools import combinations

keys = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']

cols2 = df2.columns
d = {k: f'{k}_2' for k in keys}

out = (pd.concat([df1.merge(df2
                            .rename(columns=d),
                            left_on=c,
                            right_on=[d[k] for k in c],
                            how='inner').assign(rank=i)
                  for i in range(len(keys), 0, -1)
                  for c in combinations(keys, i)
                  ], ignore_index=True)
         .loc[lambda x: x.groupby(keys)['rank'].idxmax()]
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

Output:
    id1   id2   id3  value1     value2  value3   id1_2   id2_2   id3_2  valuex  valuey  valuez  rank
0  1001  9001  3001    blue     square    True  1001.0  9001.0  3001.0    1000     2.5       5     3
1  1005  9001  3001  yellow     circle   False  1001.0  9001.0  3001.0    1000     2.5       5     2
2  1009  2001  3001   black  rectangle    True  1001.0  9001.0  3001.0    1000     2.5       5     1
3  1010  9001  5001    blue       star   False  1001.0  9001.0  3001.0    1000     2.5       5     1

